# How to pass data between controllers using directive?

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I have a controller called `ClaimController` that stores various object such as `Patient`, `Prescriber`, and others. To keep things simple and to be able to reuse, I create another controller `PatientController`, and similarly other controllers for each component that I need. So, with that said, the snippet of the `ClaimController` looks like the following.

```
testApp.controller('ClaimController', [
   '$scope', ..., 
   function($scope, ...){
       var vm = this;
       vm.Patient = {}
       .....
}]);
```

Then the `PatientController` looks like this:

```
testApp.controller('PatientController', [
    '$scope', ... , 
    function ($scope, .. ){
          var vm = this; 
          vm.Patient = {};
          ....         
}]);
```

The reason I have the object vm.Patient in both `PatientController` and `ClaimController` is so that I can use `PatientController` somewhere else and also associate Claim for the given Patient.

So, `PatientController`stores Patient object (or any changes to it). Then when Save button is clicked on `ClaimController`, the `vm.Patient` object should have `vm.Patient` object from `PatientController`. For this, I even created a directive:

```
testApp.directive('patientInfo', function(){
      return {
           restrict: 'A',
           transclude: false,
           templateUrl: 'path/to/template', 
           controller: 'PatientController',
           controllerAs: 'patCtrl',
           scope: {
               patient: '='
           },

           link: function(scope, element, attrs){


           }
      }
}
```

The template:

```
<div ng-controller="ClaimController as ctrl">
    <div patient-info patient="ctrl.Patient"></div>
</div>
```

But this is not working for me in the sense that `vm.Patient` in `ClaimController` object is always empty even when `vm.Patient` in `PatientController` contains data. so the data is not being passed. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried using $scope inside your controller instead of using *this*?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on this to help me understand? I used `controllerAs` in the directive.

Comment: where's the html for  `patient-info` and specifically how you pass `vm.Patient` to `patient` attribute. Sharing data like this is good case for implementing a service to do the sharing also

Comment: This is strange. I see the template in the "edit" mode, but doesn't show up in the question. I don't know what happened, had to hit CTRL+K a couple times till it showed up.

Comment: Sharing data is usually what I do, but it might not work in this case. In this case, if I use Shared Data, then I'd have to either create a button for each separate component to save, which is not very practical for the design I have. Otherwise, I'd have to set $watch or ng-blur for each field in the component to make sure they're field and then save the object in the shared data. That's too much work. The other way would be to create a notifier to save the data in Shared service which again is too much for all the components I have. I think using directie is a good way. Any thoughts?

Comment: dont see how this would work. If you assign `$scope.patient = PatientController.Patient` in your directive controller then your ClaimController.Patient would have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up creating `$watchCollection` for the array or object that I'm watching instead of each field and saved the data in the Shared Service to be used by another components at later time. I removed the directive and kept it simple by putting `$watchCollection` in `PatientController`.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('patCtrl.Patient', function(newVal, oldVal){
          SharedService.setPatient(newVal);
});
```

The template is now not dependent on `ClaimController`. Since all components have `SharedService`, the data can be retrieved by `ClaimController` when user hits the `save` button.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost correct, just one mistake in your code.You need use data-method instead of "patient-info patient"

```
<div ng-controller="ClaimController as ctrl">
<div data-method="ctrl.Patient"></div>
</div>
```